# Understanding view controllers with navigation bar and table view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to understand how to use view controllers properly.

For example, in a project that I am working on, I created tab bar application and I want to design a settings view.

I am now confused if I should add a view controller or table view controller. If I add a table view controller, I can't add a navigation bar and if I add a view controller I can't add a table view with static properties.

My goal is to make something like facebook messenger's settings view

[image]

in this panel, is it a view controller with table view or is it table view controller with navigation bar ?

And what is your suggestions on designing a settings view with basic user inputs such as first name, last name, gender etc. ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You want a UINavigationController for the settings with its root controller set to be  a UITableViewController. That gives you the navigation bar and the table view. This also lets you push controller on if you need to when selecting settings which require another view controller say.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UuTableViewController embedded inside a UINavigationController.

You do this in the Storyboard file. Select the table view controller and then in menu options Editor->Embed in->Navigation Controller.  Don't forget to set the table view of the table controller to static.

Comment: yeah thanks, it looks ok but how can i add a panel like above containing the picture, it doesn't let me to do that in table view controller ?

Comment: You create a UIView to encapsulate the image. You then set the tableView's tableHeaderView property to that view.

Comment: i did it, it looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/c8q5lpj52va6v83/Screenshot%202015-03-27%2003.12.39.png?dl=0 when i run it on simulator it looks weird like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/47soi7luwii8auh/Screenshot%202015-03-27%2003.13.36.png?dl=0

Comment: Looking at the screenshots, I think that is the intended behavior. First, try filling information into each of the static cells. Then, via, code, in for example viewDidLoad: or viewWillAppear: create the UIView programmatically. Attach a UIImageView and UILabel to the UIView as subviews and then set the table's tableHeaderView property.

Answer (score 0):

To use static cell which perfectly suited for the kind of setting viewController the only option is create `UITableViewController` in storyboard.

If you are comfortable with storyboard you can drag a view to the position above the tableView Xcode will give you a clue when it recognize the view as the tableView's `tableHeaderView` then layout the headerView in storyboard.

If not you can init the header view in `UITableViewController.m` and assign it to tableView.tableHeaderView